What is the difference between manually extracting data and using a GET vs POST request with jquery AJAX?
I've developed a website using Python Flask, which includes a form with two dropdowns and a slider. I'm looking to retrieve the selected values from these form elements and send them to the python flask route by using jQuery AJAX. I am uncertain on whether I should use a GET or POST request or use Javascript to manually extract the data.
The code below shows how I am manually extracting data from the form. the console correctly logs the values whenever a change occurs, but I am unsure on if this is the correct method of obtaining the values as I have seen others use GET and POST requests to obtain form values.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        // Get the value of the slider
        var groupSize = $('#groupsize-input').val();

        // Get the value of the subjects dropdown
        var subject = $('select[name="subjects"]').val();

        // Get the value of the difficulty dropdown
        var difficulty = $('select[name="difficulty"]').val();

        
        // Log the values to the console for debugging
        console.log('Group Size:', groupSize);
        console.log('Subject:', subject);
        console.log('Difficulty:', difficulty);

        
    });


I don't know how you'd ever compare "get value from DOM" and "contact server to get value from there". At a basic level, they both "give you some value". But at the basic level looking at a clock and reading a book also both "give information". Not really comparable, though. If the data you want is not on the server, then making an AJAX call to there makes as much sense as reading a book to find out what time it is now.

I don't understand what you want to do - if you don't use JavaScript then it will use GET/POST automatically to send data but it will also reload full page. If you want to send data without reloading page - then you have to use JavaScript (pure JavaScript or jQuery) and send it to server (use GET or POST in pure fetch() or using ajax.get(), ajax.post() in jQuery)

if you want to use request GET/POST to get values from dropdowns and slider then it is useless because when user change values in dropdowns and slider then browser doesn't send these values automatically to server (if user doesn't press button send) - and only browser know these values. Server doesn't know these values yet.

requests GET/POST can be useful when value from one dropdown has to change values in other dropdown. Browser may get value from one dropdown, send it to server and server may use it to get correct values from database, and send new values to browser which will replace them in second dropdown. Similar when you have input field which has to show autocomplete values - it may send current value from input to server and server may search values in database, send them to browser which will show it as list.

like @furas said, that data you extracted is known only to the browser. you must now send it to the server for it to be useful. POST is the usual way.

GET/POST don't extract anything, they're just methods for server access

@diggusbickus So I can retrieve the data how I did using javascript, but then I need to send this data back to the flask side using a POST request, correct?

yes, if you stop form using event.preventDefault() then you have to send data on your own using $.post(). This allows for (1) check data before sending - and inform user that it has wrong data (e.g. password is too short) (2) you can update page/HTML without reloading all page.

When user changes values in widgets (e.g dropdown, slider, input) then browser doesn't send it automatically to server but it waits until user presses button.
So using GET/POST to get these values is totally useless. And it would need extra code on server to get values from browser and keep it (in memory, on disk, in database), and later it would need another code to get it (from memory, from disk, from database) and send it back to browser.
GET/POST can be useful only if you have widget which content depends on value selected in other widget.
For example you may have two dropdown. In first you select country and second dropdown should show only cities in this country - and then JavaScript could use GET/POST to send country to server and it should have function which sends back cities for this country.
Other example: user write text in input and JavaScript send this to server and it sends back all results matching this word - and JavaScript display it as list, and user can select value from list. This is how can work autocomplementation (e.g. when you search something in Google)
